# Windows: copy files and change extension without duplicates

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, file-transfer, robocopy

I have a directory that has image files without extension. Let us say it to be `D:\initial\`. Now I want to copy those files over to `D:\final\` directory and change the extension to `.jpg` for each file.

My solution using ROBOCOPY:

```
@echo off

SET srcDir=D:\initial\
SET destDir=D:\final\

echo Copying files from %srcDir%
ROBOCOPY %srcDir% %destDir% /s /min:102400
echo Copying done

cd %destDir%

echo Renaming to JPG
ren *. *.jpg
```

However, there are certain conditions:

1. Copy only those files that are greater than 100 KB in size.
2. Do not delete files in the source directory.
3. The source directory will at certain periods, get newer files; copy them to the destination directory (manually, no automation needed here)

My solution meets the first two conditions, but when I run again after new files arrive, the older ones get copied over too thus giving error at renaming.

Comment: Use the `/MAXAGE:n` option?

Comment: Your third point says you will do it manually, so where's the problem?

Comment: @Seth I meant that the script shouldn't be timed to run periodically; that can be done manually. However, it must account for duplicates.

Comment: Rename files in the source directory and just run robocopy like usual. Robocopy should optimize and skip existing files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check file size and if destination file exists with an iterating for on the sourcefiles.

And use <s>x</s>copy instead of invoking robocopy every time what would be overkill here.

Copying to the new name with extension in one go eliminates the need to rename.

```
@echo off

SET "srcDir=D:\initial"
SET "destDir=D:\final"

echo Copying files from %srcDir%
For %%A in ("%srcDir%\*.") do (
    if %%~zA gtr 102400 if not exist "%destDir%\%%~nA.jpg" copy "%%~fA" "%destDir%\%%~nA.jpg" >NUL
)
echo Copying done
```

Comment: Tries to copy `D:\final\D:\initial\file.jpg` with the error `Does ... specify a file name or directory name on the target?`

Comment: Sorry, forgot to insert the `~n` modifier which uses only the name from source file without drive,path.

Comment: Works well, but now it ask confirmation every time if the target is a file or directory. Also, when I run again, it asks if I want to overwrite for all files (which is no)

Comment: It's not my day, the modifier was also missing in the check. Please try again.

Comment: Ah yes! It can get irritating at times; thank you so much :) The overwrite confirm is gone; though it still asks me every time if the target is a file or a directory `Does D:\final\file.jpg specify a file name or a directory name on the target?` for all the files

Comment: Let's take copy without x and we should be good. To suppress the message `1 file(s) copied` apppend `>NUL` to the copy

Comment: Perfect! I never looked at the `copy` command

Answer (score 0):

`xcopy <srcDir> <destDir>.<append>`

example 
`xcopy c:\Photos_with no_extensions\*  c:\Jpegs\*.jpg`

or for you `xcopy D:\initial\* D:\final\*.jpg`

It will copy all the files in the first director to the second and add .jpg to the end. One drawback is it just adds on the new extension i.e. file.pdf would become file.pdf.jpg

Comment: Thanks! And how about overwrites? Does this command replace the files with same name in `<destDir>` or does it give an error copying them?